# equivalent non-opensource database of postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, open-source, licensing

Actually we  have been asked not to use open source databsae. So, Now I have to use proprietary database. Now my doubt is What is best equivalent Proprietary   database of postgresql and  also it should be cost effective.

Please give some suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decision maker here has some weird ideas - specifically *not* open source, but they don't care what you use so long as you *don't* have the source code? That's *nuts*.

Maybe they don't understand open source licenses and are confusing GPLv3 with [the simple BSD/MIT-like license PostgreSQL is under](http://www.postgresql.org/about/licence/)? They might have images of "open source" meaning some kind of terrible viral license that takes all their patents and forces them to open source all code that it touches (which isn't true even of GPLv3, btw). Try sending them [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#3-clause_license_.28.22Revised_BSD_License.22.2C_.22New_BSD_License.22.2C_or_.22Modified_BSD_License.22.29), [FreeBSD's article on the license](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/bsdl-gpl/article.html), and that of [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq1.html#ReallyFree). They should also read [the OSI FAQ](http://opensource.org/faq). If they're still determined to waste their money after reading that and doing a little basic research, there's no saving them.

In that case, I would take the PostgreSQL source code, rename it "ProprietaryDB", whack on a restrictive all-rights-reserved license, and sell it to them for $5000/server for a perpetual license. PostgreSQL is under a BSD-like license and you're permitted to do this so long as you don't delete the copyrights from the sources or claim you wrote it. I'll gladly do this for you for as little as $4000/server, a real bargain ;-)

More seriously, there are [quite a few proprietary PostgreSQL forks already](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_derived_databases), notably:

- ParAccel
- Greenplum Database
- EnterpriseDB Postgres Plus Advanced Server

... and Amazon will sell you a ParAccel based DB as a service, Redshift, too.

Amazon RDS PostgreSQL is arguably a closed source fork too, though it tracks mainline PostgreSQL closely and there doesn't seem to be much real difference if any.